# How to extract negative/positive floating point/whole numbers and math signs used in this expression?

Tags: regex

I have different strings in the form of:

```
"-33.3*-50" 

"3+5"

"-109.51+-33"
```

I am looking to have the following output:

```
"-33.3", "*", "-50"

"3", "+", "5"

"-109.51", "+", "-33"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a format of `x (math symbol) y`, then following regex will work:

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\*|\+|\-|\/|\%)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7IBiNd/3)

```
(                  # Group 1
  -?                 # Match if - symbol present
  \d+                # Match digits
  (?:\.\d+)?         # Non-capturing group - match if contains float part
)                  # Close Group 1
(                  # Group 2
  \*|\+|\-|\/|\%     # Match math symbols *,+,-,/,%, separated using | -> or. Add others as needed.
)                  # Close Group 2
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)  # Group 3 structure is same as Group 1 above.
```

Every individual part of the equation is in an individual group. E.g. `-33.3` is captured in **Group 1**, `*` is captured in **Group 2**, `-50` is captured in **Group 3**.

You can then substitute with `"$1", "$2", "$3"` in order to get the result that you want (see bottom of Regex Demo page).

Answer (score 1):

This expression might be somewhat close,

```
[+*/]|[0-9.-]+
```

without validation.

#### Test

```
import re

string = """
-33.3*-50
3+5
-109.51+-33
-109.51+-33/24
"""

print(re.findall(r'[+*/]|[0-9.-]+', string))
```

#### Output

```
['-33.3', '*', '-50', '3', '+', '5', '-109.51', '+', '-33', '-109.51', '+', '-33', '/', '24']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CFloCX/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/CFloCX/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---